# Is there a widget or setting to allow taking/making a one-press Evernote PAGE CAMERA

Tags: evernote

Evernote has this new feature: Page Camera which is sort of like a camera/scanner.
It crops the photo down to the page you're taking a photo of and adjusts the contrast, etc. Very slick.

But it's buried in the menu.

There is a widget for taking a photo note but I can't find one for quickly (one button) creating a  **Page Camera Note**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Page Camera is now included in the Evernote Widgets.
Add it to your Droid screen just like you would any of the other Evernote Widgets.